Shortcut to navigate to overlay feature?
There is a feature now that when you scroll down the class & function name that you are in are shown as an overlay (it might be called breadcrumbs).

In the above example BatchCreateTester is the class that we are in, that we see the overlay of.
Is there a shortcut way to go to the function & class that gets overlaid?

A shortcut way to what, exactly?

This option is called as 'Sticky lines while scrolling'. You can easily disable it by right-clicking on the sticky lines in the editor. And when you want to enable it again, you have to right-click on the line number pane -> Appearance -> Check the 'Show sticky lines'. If you want to assign a keyboard shortcut for it you can use IntelliJ plugin 'Key Promoter X'.

@jonrsharpe clarified question: a shortcut way to go to the overlaid class

You're already in the overlaid class. If you mean to the line where the definition starts, given you can see the number you can find that line, but I don't think sticky lines have any additional shortcut actions of their own (although they are clickable).
